# How to wrap single callback with multiple flows

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have 3rd party a library, where you can subscribe to some *topic* to receive updates on that *topic* (with callback). But the problem is, that when you call the subscribe method with the same *topic* again, the previous subscription is silently replaced with the new one.

Now, I'd like to replace the callback with `Flow`. So I wrote the following code:

```kotlin
val flow: Flow<Message> = callbackFlow {
    lib.subscribe(topic) { message -> offer(message) }
    awaitClose { lib.unsubscribe(topic) }
}
```

But when I call `collect` multiple times, only the last one is getting the messages.

So how can I achieve this:

- Have multiple subscriptions to the same topic
- When the last subscriber closes/cancels, unsubscribe from the given topic.

I've already looked at `BroadcastChannel`, but I couldn't find anything to solve the second requirement. And I've just started exploring `Flow`s, so maybe there is some simple wrapper which I simply missed.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your `Flow` to a `SharedFlow` (of course, you could still expose it as the more abstract `Flow` type), then subsequent subscribers will be added without re-executing the block that's passed to `callbackFlow()`, meaning that the original subscriber to the library won't be replaced.

The Kotlin Flow library provides a `Flow<T>.shareIn(): SharedFlow<T>` extension, which makes it really easy to convert to a `SharedFlow`.

There's one other important part to this answer. When you call `shareIn()`, you'll need to pass `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` as one of the args. This is crucial in your use case because **without that, `awaitClose()` may not be called**, which means that you wouldn't be unsubscribed from the library. With `WhileSubscribed`, completely unsubscribing from the `SharedFlow` will also result in unsubscribing from the original `Flow`, which will trigger a call to `awaitClose()`.

Your code might look like this:

```
val flow: Flow<Message> = callbackFlow {
    lib.subscribe(topic) { message -> offer(message) }
    awaitClose { lib.unsubscribe(topic) }
}.shareIn(coroutineScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), replay = 0)
```

From the doc on [`shareIn()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html):

> WhileSubscribed() — starts the upstream flow when the first subscriber appears, immediately stops when the last subscriber disappears...